# Full screen isn't filling screen

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

When I start up Minecraft and put it into full screen mode this is what happens: [image]

I've tried restarting my game and changing the resolution.

Comment: Could you possibly give more detail? What resolution screen are you using, are you using any custom launch options for Minecraft?

Comment: It probably works better in 1.13+.

Answer (score 1):

press f11 once then press the maximise button (present near the close button. Just like any other window) and press f11 again. This should work.

Answer (score -3):

Try pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> (multiple times if needed), it should work!